# Java equivalent of JavaScript's String.match()

Tags: java, javascript, regex

What is the Java equivalent of JavaScript's `String.match()`

I need to get an array or a list of all matches

Example:

```
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
console.log(str.match(/e/gim));
```

gives

```
["e", "e", "e"]
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check [Regex tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Your code should look something similar to this:

```
String input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("e").matcher(input);

while ( matcher.find() ) {
    // Do something with the matched text
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes in the `regex` package. Specifically the `Matcher.find` method. That does not return an array, but you can use it in a loop to iterate through all matches.

Answer (score 1):

`String.matches(String regex)` is a more direct equivalent, but only use it for one-off regexes. If you'll be using it multiple times, stick with `Pattern.compile` as suggested.