# How to Handle javascript method String.prototype.match() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I have Javascript Function as below and I want to convert this code in Java.

```
 function foo() {
        var str = "a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2";
        var res = str.match('a=rtpmap:(\\d+) (\\w+)/(\\d+)');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448893/java-equivalent-of-javascripts-string-match) link but it didn't helped me.

Comment: As in that accepted answer of that question you linked, `matcher.group` has list of element I guess, have you tried that?

Comment: @Durga tried that, but it only returns the matched string as whole, while javascript returns first string in first index and matched values from parentheses in subsequent indexes. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 2):

In the link you have provided is actually the answer to your question. `matcher` returns a list of matched elements and you can access them like this:

```
String input = "a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("a=rtpmap:(\\d+) (\\w+)/(\\d+)").matcher(input);

while ( matcher.find() ) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // 111
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // opus
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); // 48000
}
```

As you can see it returns the elements in the same way as JavaScript. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks a Lot..Woking Like Charm!!

Comment: Works great..! can we get a length of matched group?

Comment: If you want to get the amount of all matched groups then use `groupCount()` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()). And if you want to get the length of the specific group then use `length()` method from `String` class since this is a string